# 1 Application gatway hosting multiple websites on 1 backend VMSS

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, website-hosting

i'm looking for the following configuration :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj09d.png)

1. The backend pool is azure vmss
2. there are 2 websites and both websites are running on vmss
3. SSL termination should be active and application gateway SSKU v1
4. mutual authentication tls/ssl would be nice to have

So how could i do it with application gateway?
I didn't find a configuration for this infrstructure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-site listeners would be the best solution based on your configuration discussed above

- Would suggest you to refer the below link on how to create an application gateway hosting multiple sites by using listeners using PowerShell.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-multiple-sites-powershell

- For more information about hosting multiple sites on backend address poll of application gateway refer the below link :
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/multiple-site-overview

Comment: Ok thanks. Multi-site listeners. But this feature is in preview and is available only for Standard_v2 and WAF_v2 SKU of Application Gateway. This is my problem.

Comment: @learnazure Multi-site listeners have been public for years now, I use them extensively (~300 sites, ~600 listeners, 3 instances of AppGateway).

The part that is in preview is and only available on the v2 SKUs *Wildcard listeners* , these are different and a separate thing to Multi-site listeners.  
I have experimented with Wildcard listeners, it's handy if you have multiple zones of the same domain but be aware they must ALL go to the same backend pool. You can't spilt addresses that have the same second level domain between diffferent backend pools

Comment: I would also highly recommend that you consider upgrading to Application Gateway v2 SKU. Apart from being faster and cheaper there are a number of security and feature benefits that make the transition worthwhile.

Comment: ok thanks. So i should use multi-site listeners. v2 SKU ist too expensive for what i want to do. I have only 3-5 Websites with not much traffic. Could i use for each listener the same port 443 with a certificate for this explicit website? I have no idea how to do this exactly. Could you give me an example maybe Azure CLI will be fine too.

Comment: @learnazure, As per the documentation using multi site listeners you can configure 100+ website on one application gateway.
Here is the reference document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-components#types-of-listeners)

Comment: Thanks - i will try my best to get run.

Comment: @learnazure - if the above answer provided was helpful ? If so could you please accept the answer as solution. This could help other community users who have similar query in the future.